# I would call this advanced tuple manipulation?

Tags: python, function, tuples

I'm trying to take a list of tuples that contain the name of individual functions and its arguments and instantiate them..this will be used for a multi-threading application.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

def func1(df,arg2,arg3):
    print 'func1'
    print type(df)
    print arg2,arg4

def func2(arg1,df,arg3,arg4):
    print 'func2'
    print arg1
    print type(df)
    print arg3,arg4

list_of_func_tups = [(func1,df,'two','three'),(func2,'one',df,'three','four')]

for tup in list_of_func_tups:
    f = tup[0]
    args = tup[1:]

    results = f(args)
```

But the problem is that `args` is still seen as a tuple, hence, the error stating that only one argument was given.

```
TypeError: func1() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Is there a way that I can somehow get args seen as its respective individual arguments? Maybe a type of for loop or something? Anythin?

Comment: You should use the asterisk: so `f(*args)`.

Comment: SOO Freaking simple!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a way to **feed the tuple as *positional arguments***. You can do this by using a **leading asterisk (`*`)**:

```
result = f(*args)
```

This is documented in the [documentation of function calls](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#calls):

> If the syntax `*expression` appears in the function call,
>   **`expression` must evaluate to an iterable**. Elements from this iterable are treated as if they were **additional positional
>   arguments**; if there are positional arguments *x1,..., xN*, and
>   expression evaluates to a sequence *y1, ..., yM*, this is equivalent to
>   a **call with *M+N*** positional arguments *x1, ..., xN, y1, ..., yM*.

Answer (score 3):

Let's define a function:

```
def f(arg1, arg2, arg3):
     return arg1 + arg2 + arg3
```

As Willem mentions, you can flatten a tuple or list with an asterix.

```
f(*(1, 2, 3))
```

You can use the double asterix for dictionaries

```
f(**{'arg1': 1, 'arg2': 2, 'arg3': 3})
```